# ASP.NET Compiles on page load, but not on Ctrl+Shift+B

Tags: asp.net, debugging, reference, cassini

during debug in cassini the code runs fine, but when I explictly build it, the compile breaks on an object saying it can't find the reference.  During a breakpoint shows the proper reference to the object, and I can view the debug intellisense.

The code itself is simple

```
using CFTW.Controls;
...
controls_LatestPresentations c = LoadControl("~/controls/LatestPresentations.ascx") as controls_LatestPresentations;
c.loadContent();
return RenderControl(c);
```

The control is a simple user control, with the namespace CFTW.Controls.  The calling code is in a webcontrol, which lives in the same folder.  I even tried adding the calling code to the same namespace.

EDIT: The biggest issue is that I cannot publish the dll's.  Well, at a high level anyway.

Comment: This is silly, but... do a "Clean Solution", make sure there are no stale dlls kicking around, and then do a rebuild?

Comment: @Anna Lear - not silly at all.

Comment: Cleaning it was the first thing I tried. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a web site (created by File->Create Web Site), then you are not using a project. Unlike every other project type in Visual Studio, web sites don't have project files, and don't actually build until runtime.

Comment: Then why does ctrl+shift+B blow up, as well as publish, but loading the page and control doesn't?